# How can I select elements that have no class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

If my document looks like this (lots and lots more of those `<i...>` though without any particular order)

```
<i class="special">abc</i>
<i>def</i>
<i>xyz</i>
<i class="another">rfd</i>
```

The **order** of the elements **in the example** is also **just arbitrary**, e.g. there is **no order** to them.

I want a css selector that gives me only the `<i>` where no class is set (not even using javascript).

How'd I do that?

Edit: I have specified the question, since they do not come ordered.

Comment: Next time, when changing a question where given answers answered the original question, please at least upvote those for their time spent on helping you ... and if they become completely invalid, post a new question with the new (or forgotten) requirements.

Comment: The original question was: "How can I select elements that do not have any class?". My mistake was to not emphesize thorowly that there is no order.

Comment: @LGSon Should I pose the question again now since you downvoted it? I mean google does not give me anything if I search for "css no class" and I'd consider this pretty important, so I'd rather see it upvoted for the communities sake...

Comment: Well, not needed now since the change wasn't dramatically big and I guess you upvoted the answers ... and I didn't down vote, will normally tell if and why

Comment: hmm, sry then, thanks for the tip about the way to edit questions

Comment: I decided to upvote now though, as it is a common problem many have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector with an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to find elements that don't have a `class`.

```
i:not([class]) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: does this work even if there are some javascript hacks at work that change classes and stuff like that?

Comment: @JohnSmith Changing classes dynamically with JavaScript isn't a hack. Yes, this CSS rule will not be applied if classes are added dynamically.

Comment: great this is what I want! I will accept your answer once stacky lets me

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth-child` selector:

```
i:nth-child(2)
```

Comment: sry I have not been specific enough, there is no order to the elements

Answer (score 1):

John,  I think the best way to select that element is to use the selector:

```
i.special + i:not(special):not(another), i.another + i:not(special):not(another)
```

The plus symbol gives you adjacent siblings to the initial element selected.  The comma is a separator between the objects beings selected.    I hope that this helps.

Comment: sry I have not been specific enough, there is absolutely no order to the elements

Comment: Just updated with not selectors.  I'm not sure if it will work but I suspect it may be closer to what you are looking for.